# React Not rendering <h1> tag

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to UI an have started with React js. I could create the Login and Register page and both works fine. In the Demo.js which contains a simple h1 tag , it shows a blank white page.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. No console errors or compilation errors

index.js and demo.js below :

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min";
import $ from "jquery";
import Popper from "popper.js";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./css/index.css";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import Register from "./screens/Register";
import Demo from "./screens/Demo";
import Dashboard from "./screens/Dashboard";
import reportWebVitals from "./utilityJS/reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="demo" element={<Demo />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
const fusionHiring = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("demo"));
fusionHiring.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();

// Demo.js

function Demo() {
  return <h2 className="fs-xxl fw-500 mt-4 text-white">Show Demo</h2>;
}

export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your code here, but I notice you have the class `text-white` on the `h2` tag of your `demo` component. Could it be that you also have a white background (as it is by default) and therefore you don't see the title ?

Try selecting all the text on your page just to be sure it's not just hidden.

Comment: The background is grey